# К чему относится оператор разыменовывания в Си?

Tags: c++, c, указатели

В разных источниках встречаю разное написание

```
int *address_0f_x = &longitude;
int* address_0f_x = &longitude;
int * address_0f_x = &longitude;
```

Компилируются все варианты, мне нравится второй, но к чему всё-таки правильно относить *?

Comment: а что тут такого  полезного видели люди?...

Comment: Для компилятора все одинаково, я пишу как в первом варианте.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

К **переменной**. Только это не разыменование, а объявление указателя.

Пишите, как хотите, только помните, что

```
int *p1, *p2;
```

объявление **двух** указателей, а

```
int* p1, p2;
```

указателя `p1` и переменной `p2` типа `int`.

Comment: отлично сказано

Answer (score 4):

*tl;dr;* `*` при объявлении переменной не является оператором разыменования, а является частью составного имени типа; имеет смысл использовать исключительно вариант 3.

```
int * address_0f_x = &longitude;
```

Исторически в С была симметрия объявления переменных-указателей и их использования. Объявляя переменную как `int *p` можно было сказать, что операция `*p` дает `int`. Кроме того, такой синтаксис позволял экономить байты текста в исходниках за счет объявления нескольких переменных в одной строке.

Однако с появлением С++ и добавлением в него костылей для обозначения ссылок такая симметрия исчезла. Объявляя переменную как `int &p` нельзя сказать что операция `&p` дает `int`. А необходимости экономии байтов на исходных текстах программ исчезла, соответственно объявление нескольких переменных в одной строке стало индикатором маргинального и потенциально дефективного кода.

Таким образом, имеет смысл разделять объявление переменной на ее тип `int *` и название самой переменной `p`. Так как тип в общем случае не может быть записан вплотную к идентификатору переменной (например запись `intp;` будет не корректна), то по соображениям единообразия имеет смысл не делать исключения для составных типов и всегда отделять тип от наименования переменной.

По аналогии, так как составляющие типа в общем случае не могут быть записаны вплотную друг к другу (например запись `longlongunsignedint` будет некорректна), то по соображениям единообразия имеет смысл не делать исключения для частей `*` `&` и `&&` и всегда разделять составляющие типа.

Ну а еще лучше по возможности использовать алиасы типов, а не составные типы.

Comment: имеет смысл использовать исключительно вариант 3.  С этим я не  соглашусь.

Comment: При такой записи болтается эта звездочка, как какой-то предмет в проруби ... (не эстетично)

Answer (score 1):

`int* p;`  Тип все тот же `int`, а `*` лишь обьявляет, что переменная это не обьект, а указатель на тип. Так что выделяется память не для типа, а память, равному одному машинному слову(независимо от типа), где хранится адрес обьекта. Я бы отнес(мысленно, а не в записи) знак к переменной, хотя сам имею привычку писать по образцу второго варианта.

Comment: Раз уж мысленно относите, так и пишите вплотную к переменной

Comment: @avp, это дело привычки. У каждого свой стиль.